# When i press a button how to get time at that time and set to a text field

Tags: android, android-studio-2.3

Im trying to create a chat application (mobile app). When i press send button i need to set the time at the moment to a textview

Comment: Each piece of this question is easily googlable. For example, "get the current time in Java" or "respond to a button click in Android".

Comment: I dont want to use current time i want to get the time at the moment when i press the button

Comment: I don't understand the difference.

Comment: In onClick method of button call System.currentTimeMillis() you will get the the time when button is pressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to get the current Date and time from system and then display on your textview. Try this -

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
your_textView.setText(dateFormat.format(new Date());
```

Comment: I need to to use the time at the moment dont want to use real time

Comment: What do you mean by time at the moment? How is it different from realtime

Comment: After i setting the time i dont want updating the time

Comment: Why would it update the time until you do the textview settext again? If you want to save the time somewhere, save it in a model object on click of button along with the chat message and show that time in the textview

Answer (score 2):

```
    Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(v -> {

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(" d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ");
        String time =  format.format(calendar.getTime());

        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.cdt);
        textView.setText(time);
    });

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can try following:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
YOUR_TEXT_VIEW.setText(sdf.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
```

Comment: He is looking to set the time and your date format only sets the date and not time.

Comment: you can simply add HH:mm:ss to get the time as well

Comment: @HemalHerath Please edit your question to show exactly what you tried. Also show what the results were and explain what is different from what you want.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this it may help you

```
 Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int a = calendar.get(Calendar.AM_PM);
    String time;
    if(a == Calendar.AM) {
     time = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR)+":"+calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE)+"AM";
    }
    else {
        time = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR)+ ":"+calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE)+"PM";
    }
    textView.setText(time);
```